# Visual studio debug tooltip - hide variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, tooltip

We have a class that used almost everywhere in our program that looks like this

```
class A : public B<type>
{
public:
static const A defaultValue;

};
```

Problem here is that the tooltip in the debugger shows the "defaultvalue" always, so you have to expand the whole thing it to show the "type" value in the base class, ie. the value I*m interested in. This would not be an issue if it was once in a while, but I do this a bilion times daily ....

Is there anyway to hide a static value like "defaultvalue" with a pragma or re-arrange the order so the value "type" is shown in the tooltip ?

Re-writing the class is a last option, its really driving me insane .....

Answer (score 0):

In the tooltip, no, but you can add a variable in the watch window called `defaultValue.type` and inspect the value directly there.

Comment: Wont work, I need it to show directly whenever I inspect a class contaning A

Comment: @user1488324 is writing a plugin an option?

Comment: I'm very close to the point either re-writing the class or writing a plugin.